# Filtering and then selecting shows wrong output: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate

I have a nested checkbox tree where in I can filter out the items based on the search field . Scenario wise when I search it selects the item but whenever I remove the search item it is not retained. I am trying to search `http`, and when I check and then remove the search text ,checked item is not getting retained

Can someone help me here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-checkbox-tree-add-new-child-3c0yt?file=/src/components/Widget.js:0-4239

```
import React from "react";
import CheckboxTree from "react-checkbox-tree";
import "react-checkbox-tree/lib/react-checkbox-tree.css";

const nodes = [
  {
    value: "/app",
    label: "app",
    children: [
      {
        value: "/app/Http",
        label: "Http",
        children: [
          {
            value: "/app/Http/Controllers",
            label: "Controllers",
            children: [
              {
                value: "/app/Http/Controllers/WelcomeController.js",
                label: "WelcomeController.js"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            value: "/app/Http/routes.js",
            label: "routes.js"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: "/app/Providers",
        label: "Providers",
        children: [
          {
            value: "/app/Http/Providers/EventServiceProvider.js",
            label: "EventServiceProvider.js"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "/config",
    label: "config",
    children: [
      {
        value: "/config/app.js",
        label: "app.js"
      },
      {
        value: "/config/database.js",
        label: "database.js"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "/public",
    label: "public",
    children: [
      {
        value: "/public/assets/",
        label: "Welcome",
        children: [
          {
            value: "/public/assets/style.css",
            label: "style.css"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: "/public/index.html",
        label: "index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "/.env",
    label: ".env"
  },
  {
    value: "/.gitignore",
    label: ".gitignore"
  },
  {
    value: "/README.md",
    label: "README.md"
  }
];

class Widget extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: [],
    expanded: [],
    filterText: "",
    nodesFiltered: nodes,
    nodes
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
    this.onExpand = this.onExpand.bind(this);
    this.onFilterChange = this.onFilterChange.bind(this);
    this.filterTree = this.filterTree.bind(this);
    this.filterNodes = this.filterNodes.bind(this);
  }

  onCheck(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
  }

  onExpand(expanded) {
    this.setState({ expanded });
  }

  onFilterChange (e) {
    this.setState({ filterText: e.target.value }, this.filterTree);
  }

  filterTree() {
    // Reset nodes back to unfiltered state
    if (!this.state.filterText) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        nodesFiltered: prevState.nodes
      }));
      return;
    }
    const nodesFiltered = prevState => ({
      nodesFiltered: prevState.nodes.reduce(this.filterNodes, [])
    });
    this.setState(nodesFiltered);
  }

  filterNodes(filtered, node) {
    const { filterText } = this.state;
    let children;
    if (!!node.children) {
      children = node.children.reduce(this.filterNodes, []);
    }
    if (node.label.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1 | (children && children.length)
    ) 
   {
      var expanded = [];
      expanded = [node.value, ...this.getAllValuesFromNodes(children)];
      this.setState({ expanded });
      if (!!node.children) {
        filtered.push({ ...node, children });
      } else {
        filtered.push(node);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  }

  getAllValuesFromNodes = (nodes, leafnode) => {
    const values = [];
    if (!!nodes)
      for (let n of nodes) {
        values.push(n.value);
        if (n.children) {
          values.push(...this.getAllValuesFromNodes(n.children, false));
        }
      }
    return values;
  };

  render() {
    const { checked, expanded, filterText, nodesFiltered } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="filter-container">
        <input
          className="filter-text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          type="text"
          value={filterText}
          onChange={this.onFilterChange}
        />
        <CheckboxTree
          checked={checked}
          expanded={expanded}
          nodes={nodesFiltered}
          onCheck={this.onCheck}
          onExpand={this.onExpand}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Widget;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check all children also even if they do not fall into the filter.
So I suggest adding two functions, first for find all children values and second for find node in nodes by value:

```
  getChildrenValue(item) {
    if (typeof item.children === "undefined") {
      return [item.value];
    }
    let values = [item.value];
    item.children.forEach(c => {
      values = [...values, this.getChildrenValue(c)];
    });
    return values.flat();
  }

  findNodeByValue(data, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].value === value) {
        return data[i];
      } else if (typeof data[i].children !== "undefined") {
        const nodeInChild = this.findNodeByValue(data[i].children, value);
        if (nodeInChild) {
          return nodeInChild;
        }
      }
    }
    return;
  }
```

And then you can use this in `onCheck` function:

```
  onCheck(checked, targetNode) {
    const checkedValues = { checked };
    const node = this.findNodeByValue(nodes, targetNode.value);
    const allNodes = this.getChildrenValue(node);
    if (!this.state.checked.includes(targetNode.value)) {
      checkedValues.checked = [...checkedValues.checked, allNodes].flat();
    } else {
      checkedValues.checked = checkedValues.checked.filter(
        c => !allNodes.includes(c)
      );
    }
    this.setState({ checked: checkedValues.checked });
  }
```

See full example in the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-checkbox-tree-add-new-child-6xcej?file=/src/components/Widget.js

Comment: You right, I fixed in the playground and in the comment. You are welcome!

Comment: Oh, I fixed it too:) in the playground

Comment: Sorry for the trouble again:) It does not seem like working. 1)Select style.css from Welcome, which will check its parent(Welcome) too. Now If you try to search `Welcome` its shows unchecked for `Welcome` 2) On search of `Welcome` it should return two entries, it returns `app` without displaying `WelcomeController` which is inside of `app` and `Welcome` which is inside `public`

Comment: Please, see the playground https://codesandbox.io/s/react-checkbox-tree-add-new-child-6xcej?file=/src/components/Widget.js. We also need to add parent item to our checked list